# How to write a function that work for number elemets?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a number a tag that I want when click on this a tags run a function and change href attribute of an element.I wrote this codes but get error when click on the a tags.

```
var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');
colors.each.onclick(function() {
    var dataTem;
    dataTem = this.attribute('data-theme');
    $('#color_skin').href('/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
});
```

How to change my jquery code to solve it?

```
<div id="colour-variations">
        <a class="option-toggle"><i class="icon-gear"></i></a>
        <h3>Preset Colors</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="style"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="pink"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="blue"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="turquoise"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="orange"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="lightblue"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="brown"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="green"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer :

```
var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');
colors.on('click', function () {
    var dataTem = $(this).data('theme');
    $('#color_skin').attr('href','/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
});
```

**href is not function**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event, also you don't need to iterate to bind click handler jQuery does it for you.

```
var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');
colors.on('click', function() {
    var dataTem = $(this).data('theme');
    $('#color_skin').href('/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
});
```

Also [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) can be used

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )

```js
var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');
colors.on('click', function(event) {
  var dataTem = $(this).data('theme');
  alert(dataTem)
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colour-variations">
  <a class="option-toggle"><i class="icon-gear"></i></a>
  <h3>Preset Colors</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="style">style</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="pink">pink</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="red">red</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="turquoise">turquoise</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="orange">orange</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="lightblue">lightblue</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="brown">brown</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="green"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');

 colors.on('click', function(index, item) {     
  var dataTem;
 dataTem = $(this).attr('data-theme');

 $('#color_skin').attr('href', '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.click()`

```
var colors = $('#colour-variations ul li a');
colors.click(function() {
    var dataTem;
    dataTem = this.attribute('data-theme');
    $('#color_skin').href('/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below JS -

```js
$('#colour-variations ul li a').click(function(){
 var dataTem;
    dataTem = $(this).attr('data-theme');
alert(dataTem);
  $('#color_skin').href('/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/' + dataTem + '.css');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colour-variations">
        <a class="option-toggle"><i class="icon-gear"></i></a>
        <h3>Preset Colors</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="style">rr</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="pink">ff</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="blue">ff</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="turquoise"d></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="orange">sf</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="lightblue">sdf</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="brown">sdf</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="green">sf</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```